# Increment my progress bar of password length

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, progress-bar

I am trying to increment the minimum letters text progress bar of my password input using a Javascript switch. here is my current attempt.

```
   var div = $('#progressbar>div');

        div.width(width);

        switch(password.Length)
        {
            case 1:
                div.css('width', '10%');
                break;
            case 2:
                div.css('width', '20%');
                break;
            case 3:
                div.css('width', '30%');
                break;
            case 4:
                div.css('width', '40%');
                break;
            case 5:
                div.css('width', '50%');
                break;
            case 6:
                div.css('width', '60%');
                break;
            case 7:
                div.css('width', '70%');
                break;
            case 8:
                div.css('width', '80%');
                break;
            case 9:
                div.css('width', '90%');
                break;
            case 10:
                div.css('width', '100%');
                break;

        }

        };
```

the css is as follows

```
    #progressbar {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 13px; /* (height of inner div) / 2 + padding */
    padding: 3px;
    }

    #progressbar > div {
    background-color: orange;
    width:0%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

what would i need to change to get it to work? i have tried a couple of other things but nothing is happening. FYI this is run on key up and inside a function. I am new to JavaScript so please explain :). i know i am calling the function correctly because some other functionality from it works on a different piece fo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive so you cannot use `password.Length`. Use `password.length` instead. And also I really don't know what `div.width(width)` does.
Here's working example (of course you need to fix it a bit, because it can exceed 100% width):
 http://jsfiddle.net/74c7W/2/

Comment: i have tried to add the changes and it doesn't seem to work even though i can clearly see that yours works through JSfiddle

Comment: does console say anything? does it throw any error?

Comment: it worked your changes worked just a couple of syntax errors on my behalf :), thanks

Comment: great :) I've edited fiddle so now the progressbar animates. it just looks cooler ;)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I notice from your code:

```
div.width(width);
```

The above line seems superfluous as you are going to amend the width anyway in your switch statement.

And what is `password.Length` referring to? a jquery object? It is probable that you are not switching on the value you think you are - you might need something more like `password.val().length()`

Comment: the password.length i though would work without the .val() because i have already got password declared as a variable including the val `var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();` as so before the current bit of code.

Comment: just change `.Length` to `.length()` then

Comment: do you have any error in the javascript console of your browser?